# How can I store Jalali (persian) date directly as unix timestamp and then retreive it from database

Tags: codeigniter-3

How can I store Jalali (persian) date directly as
unix timestamp and then retreive it from database.
1) Insert Jalali date to timestamp column data type.
2) Retrieve date from timestamp column as Jalali Date.

I need it in PHP Codeigniter, because my database designed
 by MySQL and PHP Codeigniter.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code. Before that, you can read [CI docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) about inserting data into DB.

Comment: This is my code in controller: $data['timestamp']     = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")); only I want to store date in Jalali Calendar not Gregorian. I found some code in PHP but I cannot match it with codeigniter.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Rather edit question and post code there. There are some libraries in github for calendar conversion. Have you tried with those?

Comment: I found something for my problem: first, take jalali date from datepicker and change it to Gregorian date to save in database. second, receiving the Gregorian and convert to jalali. Only in this time I have problem in saving converted Gregorian as timestamp.

Comment: What is the error message?